# Spark read dataframe column value as string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have dataframe in Spark 2.2 and I want to read a column value as string.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("col1" ,
      when( col("col1").isNull , col("col2") +"some_string" )
```

when col1 is null, I want to get string value in col2 and append my logic there.

Problem is I always get `col("col2")` as `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`. How can I convert this value into `String` to append my custom string?

Answer (score 2):

`lit` and `concat` will do the trick. You can give and string value using `lit` function and using `concat` function you can concatenate it to the string value of the column.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("col1", when(col("col1").isNull,
  concat(col("col2"), lit("some_string"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lit` function to change the string value to `Column` and use the `concat` function.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("col1" ,
      when( col("col1").isNull , concat(col("col2"), lit("some_string")))
```

Hope this helps! )